# Cannot execute php using apache server

Tags: php, apache, xampp, tomcat7

I'm trying to execute a simple PHP script [w3school example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) inside my browser using XAMPP Apache server but browser don't display anything at all. later i tried installing Apache tomcat 7 but result is still the same. I'm glad if anyone can give me a solution for this :)

Comment: try simply install XAMPP . Why you using tomcat

Comment: And put your code inside htdocs folder

Comment: I first tried with XAMPP but it didn't work. thats why I also installed tomcat later. I also tried placing .php file inside htdocs folder but no results. :(

Comment: Ok after installing type localhost in your browser to see what coming, if "It works" comes then it means your apache is runing smoothly

Comment: Check that error reporting is enabled

Comment: You will need to detail what steps you have taken to install it, which options you chose and where you put your file before we could do anything other than waste all our time making random guesses at what could be wrong.

Comment: localhost works fine. I already have a perfectly working Joomla site inside my htdocs but the matter is I couldn't run a simple .php file

Comment: @Anigel for now I have stopped tomcat service and only running Apache service from XAMPP. I enabled error reporting but it doesn't give any error. I have placed my .php file inside htdocs folder.

Comment: You can't have your .php file inside of your joomla install. The htaccess will route everything through index.php. Is your Joomla install in htdocs/joomla or just htdocs? Move Joomla to htdocs/joomla and create new folder for your php file: htdocs/folder. Then in the browser go to `localhost/folder/my-file.php`.